# Leaps: Running all possible linear models

Tags: r, regression

I am attempting to use the R package `leaps` to run all possible combinations of regression models -- of all possible sizes -- on a single dependent variable and greater than 50 possible predictor variables. Each variable is a vector of approximately 50 numerical values.

This is what I have tried with no success:

```
vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", ... , "var60")
xs <- as.formula(paste("yvar ~ ", paste(vars, collapse="+")))
model1 <- regsubsets(x=xs, y=yvar, really.big=TRUE, 
    method="exhaustive", data=data)
summary(model1)
```

The error I receive is:

```
Warning message:
In leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax, force.in = force.in,:
15  linear dependencies found
```

Comment: (1) That's a warning, not an error.  It shouldn't prevent you from proceeding (but you should try to figure out what it means). (2) I see that `regsubsets` doesn't actually fit all the models, which is good since there are 2^50 possible models.  Do you know if this is really going to be feasible? (3) Can we have a **reproducible** example?

Comment: @nongkrong, can you post your reproducible example (hopefully short enough to go in a comment, otherwise post as an answer and delete it later)?

Comment: @BenBolker sure, I did `dat <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(61*50), 50)), c("yvar", paste0("var", 1:60))); model1 = regsubsets(yvar ~ ., y=yvar, really.big=T, method="exhaustive", data=dat)`.  It takes a sec to run, and the `y=yvar` is redundant i think

Comment: Set `nvmax=50` to see the considerably longer run time of _all_ subsets. The default fits up to size 8.

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues here with what you are trying to do, some computational, some statistical.  Some have already been mentioned in the comments, but I think it is good to bring them all together into a single answer.

First, with 50 possible predictors there are $2^50$ possible models (which is a 16 digit number when expressed in base 10):

```
> 2^50
[1] 1.1259e+15
```

While there are some nice shortcuts in the algorithm, each possible model will still take some time to compute (and some memory to store the results in).  If we assume that your computer can calculate 100,000 models per second then it will only take 356+ years to complete (assuming that your computer does not start swapping memory to keep all the results, that really slows things down):

```
> 2^50/100000/60/60/24/365.24
[1] 356.7859
```

So I would recommend sticking with the "best" models rather than trying to fit every possible model.

Another issue (which is what leads to the warning message) is that if you only have 50 observations ("Each variable is a vector of approximately 50 numerical values") then the absolute maximum number of slopes that you can estimate uniquely (assuming you also fit an intercept) is 49, but you are trying to fit 50 slopes in the fullest model, so the matrices involved are guaranteed to singular.  Even limiting to 49 predictors will not allow for estimation of the error variance.  A common rule of thumb suggests that you should try to fit no more than 1 predictor for each 10 observations in order to get reasonable estimates of the slopes and standard errors which means you should really only go up to 5 predictor models (if you really have 50 observations, the "approximately" in your description implies missing values or other issues that may make this even less).

The best thing to learn from best subsets regression is not what the "best" model is, but rather that there rarely is a "best" model and that several models may have similarly good properties.  A better approach may be to use Lasso/LARS style fitting (depending on what question you are really trying to answer).

A couple of programming tips for the future:

Learn about the `y ~ .` approach for specifying models, that may have saved you from needing to worry about using `paste` and `as.formula`.

See `fortune(77)` in reference to the name of your data.